# download file by wget in Robot Framework test

Tags: robotframework, microsoft-edge, wget

I am trying to download a file from a webpage in edge in a Robot Framework test. While browser options are not allowed to be set due to company policies, I am trying to use wget for downloading. I use this custom keyword for it:

```
Download File  [Arguments]  ${COOKIE_NAME}  ${FILE_URL}  ${FILENAME}
   ${OUTPUT_DIR}=    Set Variable    output/
   ${COOKIE} =  Get Cookie  ${COOKIE_NAME}
   Log    name: ${COOKIE.name}, value: ${COOKIE.value}
   Run and Return RC  wget --cookies=on --header "Cookie: ${COOKIE.name}=${COOKIE.value}" -O ${OUTPUT_DIR}${/}${FILENAME} ${FILE_URL}
```

It logs correct cookie name and value, but creates only an empty file in the output directory. Should I use wget with different parameters or something else is the problem?

Comment: Have you any output produced by wget when you run that command?

Comment: Have you ever tried to independently run wget with the cookie? What's the result?